# Shallow copy vs deep copy in array containing objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Shallow copy is nothing but when trying to copy and change the contents of copied array {array containing objects and not primitive data types} the contents of the original array also got changed.

In the following case, why the dst[0]= {name : "tom"}  is a deep copy and not a shallow copy (the contents of the original array "src" is not changed). On the contrary, the second operation which is dst[0].name= "tom" is creating a shallow copy as expected and changing the contents of src. Can someone please clarify this?

```js
let src = [{
  name: 'brat'
}, {
  age: 40
}]
let dst = [...src]


// dst[0]={name:"tom"} 
dst[0].name = "tom";


console.log(`src ${JSON.stringify(src)}`)
console.log(`dst ${JSON.stringify(dst)}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because in the below line, you are not changing the copied property of src, instead you are re-assigning both 'key' and 'value' and replacing the old property altogether with a new property.

```
dst[0]={name:"tom"}
```

is the same as doing this:

```
dst[0]={newName:"tom"}
```

It's considered as dst's new property instead of the one copied from src, and that is the reason the original object does not change, because this 'name' property is not the same one that was copied from the original object.

When you use the {name : "tom" } to re-assign the value to dst, then **dst[0]**'s memory is released from the heap and a new object replaces **dst[0]** altogether, it is not the same object that was shallow copied from **src[0]**.

Comment: Got it. It totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`dst[0]={name:"tom"}` and `dst[0].name = "tom";` are not copies, they're just assignments. One changes the `dst` array (sets a new object as the first element), the other changes the first object (sets a new string for the `.name` property).

The shallow copy happens in the line `let dst = [...src]`, and if you're not changing that it's always a shallow copy where `dst` contains the *same* mutable objects as `src`.

Comment: I agree with your statement that the spread operator is creating a shallow copy here. But my confusion is in spite of both being assignment operations post shallow copy, operation 1 does not change the contents of src while operation 2 does change the contents of src.

Comment: @ryan The second one doesn't change the `src` or `dst` array themselves. It changes the object that both arrays contain.